# Python Google Spreadsheet API sorting not effective

Tags: python, api, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I use the google example https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts (just switching lines 3 and 4 for the purpose of the test) to test the Google Spreadshhet API v4 with Python v3.7.8:

- creation of a column chart
- sorting the column 'A'

The data are stored in a Spreadsheet in a google Drive where I create the column chart.

[image]

**The column chart is created but the the column 'A' is not sorted (ascending).** Hereafter the code:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

...

body = {'requests': [
    {'addChart': 
     {'chart': 
      {'spec': 
       {'title': 'Model Q1 Sales', 
        'titleTextPosition': {'horizontalAlignment': 'CENTER'}, 
        'basicChart': 
        {'domains': [
            {'domain': 
             {'sourceRange': 
              {'sources': [
                  {'sheetId': 909072886, 
                   'startRowIndex': 0, 
                   'endRowIndex': 7, 
                   'startColumnIndex': 0, 
                   'endColumnIndex': 1}]}}}], 
         'series': [
             {'series': 
              {'sourceRange': 
               {'sources': [
                   {'sheetId': 909072886, 
                    'startRowIndex': 0, 
                    'endRowIndex': 7, 
                    'startColumnIndex': 1, 
                    'endColumnIndex': 2}]}}, 
              'targetAxis': 'LEFT_AXIS'}, 
             {'series': 
              {'sourceRange': 
               {'sources': [
                   {'sheetId': 909072886, 
                    'startRowIndex': 0, 
                    'endRowIndex': 7, 
                    'startColumnIndex': 2, 
                    'endColumnIndex': 3}]}}, 
              'targetAxis': 'LEFT_AXIS'},   
             {'series': 
              {'sourceRange': 
               {'sources': [
                   {'sheetId': 909072886, 
                    'startRowIndex': 0, 
                    'endRowIndex': 7, 
                    'startColumnIndex': 3, 
                    'endColumnIndex': 4}]}}, 
              'targetAxis': 'LEFT_AXIS'}], 
         'legendPosition': 'BOTTOM_LEGEND', 
         'axis': [
             {'position': 'BOTTOM_AXIS', 
              'title': 'Model Numbers', 
              'titleTextPosition': {'horizontalAlignment': 'CENTER'}}, 
             {'position': 'LEFT_AXIS', 
              'title': 'Sales', 
              'titleTextPosition': {'horizontalAlignment': 'CENTER'}}], 
         'headerCount': 1, 
         'chartType': 'COLUMN',  
         'stackedType': 'STACKED'}, 
        'sortSpecs': [
            {'dimensionIndex': 0, 
             'sortOrder': 'ASCENDING'}]}, 
       'position': 
       {'overlayPosition': 
        {'anchorCell': 
         {'sheetId': 909072886, 
          'rowIndex': 7, 
          'columnIndex': 6}
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
]
}

response = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=file_id, body=body).execute()
```

I should get the following:

[image]

**But I get this: no effect of the sort part.**

[image]

Remark: I also tried without success for the sortSpecs

```
'dataSourceColumnReference': {'name': 'A'}
```

in place of

```
'dimensionIndex': 0
```

Don't hesitate to support me! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

When adding a Chart, `sortSpecs` is only supported for data coming from external data sources. From the [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/charts#ChartSpec):

> **sortSpecs[]**: The order to sort the chart data by. Only a single sort spec is supported. **Only supported for data source charts**.

#### Solution:

You should sort the data itself. You can do this programmatically, by adding a [sortRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#SortRangeRequest) request to your `batchUpdate`:

```
body = {
    'requests': [
        {
            'sortRange': {
                'range': {
                    'sheetId': 909072886,
                    'startRowIndex': 1,
                    'endRowIndex': 7,
                    'startColumnIndex': 0,
                    'endColumnIndex': 5
                },
                'sortSpecs': [
                    {
                        'sortOrder': 'ASCENDING',
                        'dimensionIndex': 0
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            'addChart': {
                # Add chart request body
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Connected Sheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/connected-sheets)
- [DataSource](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#DataSource)

Comment: @lamblichus, thank you for you quick answer. I will test your code. However I would like to know how to do it in the chart itself as it is explained in the [reference ](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/charts#chartspec). Maybe I don't understand it ...

Comment: @hganger I don't think you can sort it only in the chart, and not in the corresponding range of data. The `sortSpecs` are only for external data sources, as mentioned in the reference I provided.

Comment: @lamblichus. I've tested but **service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=file_id, body=body).execute()** creates an error: HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/****************************:batchUpdate?alt=json returned "Invalid value at 'requests[0]' (oneof), oneof field 'kind' is already set. Cannot set 'addChart'". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'field': 'requests[0]', 'description': "Invalid value at 'requests[0]' (oneof), oneof field 'kind' is already set. Cannot set 'addChart'"}]}]">

Comment: @hganger I can't reproduce this. I'm not getting any error when using this, the request is working successfully. You need to add the code corresponding to `addChart` request (the code you shared, but the `sortSpecs` part not needed). Did you do that?

Comment: @hganger I'm sorry I messed up with the opening/closing `{ }` when copying my code to the answer. I think I fixed it now, let me know if it works.

Comment: @lamblichus. Now it works without error.: the data in the chart are sorted. However, it is not what I expected. My expectations were: **sorting the data only in the chart but not sorting the data in the sheet**. Maybe what I expect is not possible. Thank you for your support.

Comment: @hganger As I said before, you cannot sort the data in the chart without sorting the data in the source range too. I don't think what you want to do is possible, if the data is coming from the same spreadsheet and not from an external source (that's the only circumstance in which `sortSpecs` can be used, as I mentioned in my answer).

Comment: @tanaike. Hi, as you help me in another topic with Google API, I take the opportunity to directly ask for your support. Regards.

Comment: @hganger What you want to do is just not possible. You cannot sort the chart without sorting the source data too, that's just how charts work in Google Sheets. A possible workaround could be to have the sorted data in a hidden sheet, and use that data to create the chart instead, but that's it.

Comment: @lamblichus.If it is not  possible I will consider your answer as the right one. But please could you just explain me about the sortSpecs which is directly in the chart part? (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/charts#chartspec)

Comment: @hganger They refer to sorting charts for data coming from external data sources, as I mentioned in my answer, like BigQuery data sources, not if the data is coming from the spreadsheet itself. That's what `Only supported for data source charts.` on the `sortSpecs` explanation refers to. Check the `Reference` part of my answer for more information.